# Is there a way to select one string value that contains the latest date relative to the values in the same list

Tags: r, list

I have a vector like this

```
c("The date is 1-2-23","Here it is 1-16-23",
"Here 2-16-23 is the latest", 
"4-3-23 is actually the latest","12-12-22 is the earliest")
```

I would like to be left with

```
Latest<-"4-3-23 is actually the latest"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way to parse the dates seems to be `mdy()` from the lubridate package which is now part of the Tidyverse:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(
  "The date is 1-2-23",
  "Here it is 1-16-23",
  "Here 2-16-23 is the latest",
  "4-3-23 is actually the latest",
  "12-12-22 is the earliest"
)

x[which.max(mdy(x))]
#> [1] "4-3-23 is actually the latest"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Might be the 'simple' way, but it's also fragile to the point of a single number elsewhere in the string breaking the parsing - `mdy("1 is 1-2-23 ayyy here")`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pipeline to extract, sort, and pull the most recent:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data.frame(strings = c("The date is 1-2-23","Here it is 1-16-23",
                       "Here 2-16-23 is the latest", 
                       "4-3-23 is actually the latest","12-12-22 is the earliest")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(str_extract(strings, "(\\d+-?){3}"), "%m-%d-%y")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(date)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(strings)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** with have to use class date (thanks to @thelatemail):

```
max(as.Date(regmatches(vec, regexpr("\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2}", vec)), "%m-%d-%y"))

[1] "2023-04-03"
```

**First answer:**
We could do it this way:

1. Create regex to match date with format (mm-dd-yy)
2. with `regmatches` and `regexpr` extract the date
3. use `max` for latest date
4. use `paste` for string

```
paste(max(regmatches(vec, regexpr("\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2}", vec))), "is actually the latest")

"4-3-23 is actually the latest"
```

Comment: I don't think you need to `paste` "is actually the latest" - that's in the 4th value of the original vector that you can just return. You'll have to also `as.Date()` the returned result or otherwise `10-3-23` is going to be less than `4-3-23`.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing `as.Date` and `order`ing after getting the date string with `sub`

```
stri[order(as.Date(
   sub(".*(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+).*", "\\1", stri), "%m-%d-%y"), decreasing=T)[1]]
[1] "4-3-23 is actually the latest"
```

##### Data

```
stri <- c("The date is 1-2-23","Here it is 1-16-23",
"Here 2-16-23 is the latest", 
"4-3-23 is actually the latest","12-12-22 is the earliest")
```